# how to lock and not allow the user to access the navigation bar in an android 4.2.2 tablet activity?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application for samsung galaxy tab 3 10.1 model gt-p5210. In an activity we shouldn't allow the user to access the navigation bar in any way. Currently I'm hiding the navigation bar like below.

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

But, it is not locking. When ever I swipe from top to bottom. The Navigation bar is appearing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```